# Trouble forwarding AOL email to new Gmail account

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding, imap, pop3, aol-mail

I'm helping my parents migrate from AOL to Gmail, and I'm trying to configure automatic email forwarding from AOL to the new Gmail address. (Just to be clear -- they will now use Gmail day-to-day, and get new AOL mail sent directly to the new Gmail inbox as well)

AOL used to offer a forwarding service, but it looks like it was deactivated several years ago. Gmail, however, can (in theory) set up many different services, including automatic forwarding, from most email accounts.

Gmail offers two solutions: Gmailify and a traditional POP/IMAP forwarding service. Gmailify takes my username and password, then gives an error message saying the account is not supported.

Then, I tried the POP/IMAP suggested settings, as follows:

AOL support suggests the following settings for POP:

- pop.aol.com
- port 995
- ssl enabled
- username@aol.com
- password

and for IMAP:

- imap.aol.com
- port 993
- ssl enabled
- username@aol.com
- password

However, neither of these configurations work for me. I either get a `"invalid username/password"` error, or `Missing +OK response upon connecting to the server: *` Neither solution works for this account so far. Suggestions?

Has anyone done this recently? Old forums say that the settings I have tried are correct, but I have not found this to be the case.

Comment: have you tried just the username without @aol.com in the POP or IMAP config?

Comment: Yep, I've tried both variations. AOL documentation says to include it, while the Gmail tool removes the @aol.com suffix automatically by default.

Comment: what about signing into AOL mail accounts directly and checking settings?  There might be an "enable IMAP or POP access" setting that's disabled.

Answer (score 1):

This forwarding from AOL to Gmail can no longer be done. When I inquired of AOL I received this response (11/9/18):

> Thank you for contacting the AOL Email Support Team.
>
> Unfortunately, at this moment, there is no option available that satisfies your needs. The only option to forward emails is manually, one by one. Rest assured that your email has not gone unnoticed and your suggestion will be forwarded to the development team.